# Excel copying blanks instead of zeroes

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working an a worksheet that saves data to a separate worksheet as a sort of database of previous entries. Everything was working great, but suddenly it started putting blanks into the database spreadsheet instead of zeroes. It did not previously do this, and I'm not sure what triggered the change in behavior. The bit of code I'm focusing on is this:

```
Workbooks(DatabaseName).Worksheets(WorksheetName).Cells(n.Row, i) = Workbooks(WorkBookName).Worksheets(WorksheetName).Cells(k, l).Value
```

Using the immediate viewer, I can see that .Cells(k, l).Value is returning a value of "blank" instead of zero, even though the Cell (k,l) contains a zero. To get around this, I tried setting integer variables:

```
CellValue = Workbooks(WorkBookName).Worksheets(WorksheetName).Cells(k, l).Value
DBValue = Workbooks(DatabaseName).Worksheets(WorksheetName).Cells(n.Row, i).Value
If CellValue <> DBValue Then
   Workbooks(DatabaseName).Worksheets(WorksheetName).Cells(n.Row, i) = CellValue
End If
```

This is returning a type mismatch because .Cells(k, l).Value is still returning "blank" not "0".

What's baffling me is this has been in use by several people for quite a while (several years, in fact), and it has never swapped blanks for zeroes until this week. What can I change to make this work?

**EDIT:** I rechecked the type mismatch I got after trying the method forcing integer type, and after 1200 rows of integers, there are three cells containing strings that were causing the type mismatch, not blank cells as I'd previously thought. I changed the code to only use the integer method until it reaches those strings, and I'm no longer getting the type mismatch error. Frustratingly, it is still recording zeroes as blanks.

**EDIT 2:** Problem solved! When excel was evaluating the statement:

```
If Cells(k, l).Value <> Cells(n.Row, i).Value Then
```

When (k, l) was "0" and (n.Row, i) was blank it was returning that the two were equal and skipping the "Then" statement that would write the zero to the to (n.Row, i).
I solved it by changing to

```
If Cells(k, l).Value <> Cells(n.Row, i).Value Then
....
ElseIf Cells(k,l).Value = 0 Then
....
```

Comment: Can you send `debug.print Workbooks(WorkBookName).Worksheets(WorksheetName).Cells(k, l).address(external:=true)` to the immediate window to verify that the `WorkBookName` and `WorksheetName` vars match the workbook/worksheet they are supposed to? In they were assigned according to the [Worksheet.Index property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836415.aspx) and the worksheets were reordered, then the code would be pointing to the wrong worksheet.

Comment: It returns [ALINTING.xlsm]DATA!$C$5, which is the correct workbook and worksheet

Comment: A somewhat hack-ish approach would be to check if your cell is blank, and if so use a hard-coded zero.

Comment: If the cell (number) format is set to custom (similar to `0;-0;;@`) in C5 you'll have to change from `.Cells(k, l).Value` to `.Cells(k, l).Formula` ([details about formatting](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Display-or-hide-zero-values-3ec7a433-46b8-4516-8085-a00e9e476b03) and [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-2d450d95-2630-43b8-bf06-ccee7cbe6864))

Comment: Kyle, I thought about checking for blanks and replacing them with zero, but blanks could be a legitimate entry in some cases so I don't want hard-code a zero. As far as cell formatting, it is set to "General".

Comment: @paulbica - Either [Range.Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx) or [Range.Value2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193553.aspx) should pull the zero from that custom number format. It is [Range.Text property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840217.aspx) that would not. btw, I also checked Excel Options, Show a zero in cells that have xzero value and both .Value and .Value2 returned the zero that was not displayed.

Comment: I think by this point you need to redact the workbook sufficiently that it can be made publicly distributable while still showing the error. A second (and third, fourth, etc) set of eyes on the problem as a whole would be the next logical step.

Comment: @Jeeped - thanks, and noted (another way to access the Excel option, `ActiveWindow.DisplayZeros`)

Answer (score 0):

Are those cells having numeric format or string format? Look at this:

[www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/three-ways-to-hide-zero-values-in-an-excel-sheet/](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/three-ways-to-hide-zero-values-in-an-excel-sheet/)